# Parsing a single <p> tag from many <p> tag in jsoup

Tags: java, jsoup

I want to print the line from `<p>I want only this line</p>`tag and want to ignore all other lines.

I have following html:

```
<div class="my value"> 
<h2>Head2</h2>

<p>&nbsp;</p>

<p><strong></strong>Date</p>

<p></p>

<h2><u>Head2</u></h2>

<p>&nbsp;</p>

<p>I want only this line</p>

<p>&nbsp;</p>

<p><strong><u></u></strong></p>

<p>&nbsp;</p>

<p>I do not want this line</p>

</div>
```

And my java code is:

```
String html = "link of the website that contains my html I have showed on top";
Document doc;
try {
    doc = Jsoup.connect(html).get();

    Elements link = doc.select("div.my.value");
    doc=Jsoup.parse(link.html());
    link =doc.select("p");
    String linkText = link.text();

    System.out.println("Link Text\n" + linkText);

} catch (IOException ex) {
    System.out.println("err: " + ex);
}
```

Output is:

**I want only this line I do not want this line**

But I want to print only this line **I want only this line** and want to ignore all other `<p> </p>` tags. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The key to get the what you want is creating a good selector. Let's see some examples using your HTML:

1) Selecting by the content: 
`p:contains(I want only this line)` or, if you want to be more specific, `div.my p:contains(I want only this line)`

2) Selecting by the position in the DOM: `div p:eq(6)`

In order to get the element, I prefer using this statement:
`Jsoup.parse(html).select("div.my p:contains(I want only this line)").first()`

Then you just need to check if the element returned is not null. Otherwise, you can get a NullPointException.

Comment: The value of p tag is dynamic, It can be changed any time by admin. so this will not help me

Comment: So you have to post the possible combinations. Thus, we create a selector that cover all possibilities.

Comment: There is no possible combinations

Comment: Let me explain: is the position of HTML always the same? Do they came in the same sequence? If they do, you just need to use `div.my p:eq(6)` selector. Regardless of the content inside `p` element, it's gonna get it.